# Zebra LP2844 will not print EPL2 commands ( Page mode ), only EPL1 ( Line mode) works

Tags: zebra-printers, epl

I have an LP2844 that seems to take a print job just fine, but ignores it, I don't get any errors, and no change to the LED on the printer to indicate that it got the message.

The diagnostic prints out when I hold the button down at start up, so I knew the print head and things worked.

I managed to find that you could use the button to switch the printer to EPL1/Line Mode, and when I did that, all the text I send to it prints out, but none of the drivers are written for this anymore.

So I know the print head works, the USB cable works, and so on, because I can print in line mode, but when I switch it back to Page mode, it stops responding to commands.

I tried to do a factory reset as described on Zebra website, but when I hold down the feed button, it just keeps feeding, and never does the blinking that is described there.

Has anyone seen anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiecing looks like an issue with the EPL syntax.
Does the led blinks when you send the data and have you also checked if the EPL syntax is correct?
Have you tried to use zebradesigner to create and print a label?

Comment: I have, there was no response at all, no blinking lights either.  I did manage to fix it, but I don't think it really addresses the problem I posted, by flashing firmware to the chips manually, and then it worked.   I wonder if someone used the wrong firmware or something.